# JuliaBox: How to install GitHub packages in JuliaBox? See the picture

Tags: julia

I tried `Pkg.add` and `Pkg.clone` but failed.[image: I know little about Linux\Jupyter command]

Comment: JuliaBox is now a paid service, so if you're having trouble please contact  juliabox@juliacomputing.com directly.  StackOverflow isn't going to be of much help here, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

clean cache file(env) and restart juliabox

guess there's something wrong with its workspace..